# How to let the application automatically press enter after opening a website

Tags: c#, console

Hi I am using C# to open a website and I would like to let the application press enter after opening the website. Is anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = OpenWebsite,
                UseShellExecute = true
            });
           
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Do you want to press enter **in the website** ?

Comment: @UserNam3 ya somethings like sendkey. Will let the website automatically click Enter

Comment: Sort of "I know how to easily and reliably do it with Selenium, but I want hard and shaky way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think of two ways to do this.

- Send the key to the process

Like that

```
// You need this
[DllImport ("User32.dll")] static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);

// ...

// The target process (here with firefox) but be sure to target the good one
Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox").FirstOrDefault();
if (p != null)
{
    IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(h);
    SendKeys.SendWait("Enter");
}
```

- Open whe website in your application and simulate a clic

With a webview2

```
// ...

// wbv2 is a WebView2 component displayed in your UI  
wbv2.Source = new Uri([your URL], UriKind.Absolute);

// When the navigation is complete I click in the first button
await wbv2.ExecuteScriptAsync(document.getElementsByName('button')[0].click()");
```

This is not the full code but I guess you have some clues for your goal.